# VS2019 VB.NET IDE say Imports not required but removal causes error

Tags: vb.net, ide, visual-studio-2019

Migrated a VS2010 project into VS2019 Community, went well except for 640 errors similar to this:

> Error  BC30451 'CommandType' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

If I include `Imports System.Data` the error in that module goes away, however the imports statement is dimmed and the IDE says it is unnecessary.  If I add `Data.CommandType` the error also goes away, but then the IDE suggests that `Data.` in unnecessary.

In project properties -> references -> Imported Namespaces, System.Data is checked.

In VS2010 the System.Data namespace was apparently global to my project since I did not need to import it in each module, and it looks like VS2019 is trying to do the same. I don't mind having to import the namespaces but the IDE is giving me conflicting information.

Is this a known issue or do I need to make a change to some global setting in my project?

Comment: I've experienced comparable issues in C#. The light bulb suggested to remove usings, but then they were missing. Consider reporting this problem through menu *Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem...*.

Comment: I did as suggested and reported the error. thx.